# Dropdown menu that depends on the date field using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project using JQUERY, but I'm facing a difficult situation, I usually know how to make a dropdown menu depend to another, but now i need a dropdown menu that contains the age ranges that's depend on the date typed in birth-date field, I would like that when I type in the birth-date field, the drop-down menu should automatically select the age range, but if the date field is empty it must select the "unspecified" option whose ID equals 4 which appears in the DATE_RANGE table, Please help me to solve this riddle, welcome to any suggestion.
If I made a mistake in the question asked, please explain to me what should I do, any help will be appreciated

here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" name="bd" id="bd" value=""  >

    <select class="form-control" name="rd" id="rd">
        <option></option>
        <option value"1">CAT_1</option>
        <option value"2">CAT_2</option>
    </select>
    
</div>
```

Best regards

Comment: Your code is incomplete what is the value of age range collection e.g. how many ranges are there in the select box show the php side code

Comment: why php? when you can handle this on browser client side using only pure js or jquery

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, im using an PHP framework, so i'm using it to store data into HUMAIN TABLE,  and also bring data into the dropdown menu, i have four age ranges -18 , btw 18 25, btw 25 50 , +50, I edited the question by adding some explanation, again I really appreciate your support

Comment: basically user will select the date of birth, so that means this particular part which maps the date of birth to the date range will be handled by JavaScript later on your PHP code will store the selected value in the database.

Comment: yes that's exactly it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shoes the event that listens to the change in date of birth selected by user then it passes the dob to the function which calculates the age on the basis of the age it selects the appropriate date range in the date range select box.

```js
const getAge = (dob) => { 
return ~~((new Date()-new Date(dob))/(31556952000));
};

$('#birth-date').change(function() {
    const date = $(this).val();
    const age = getAge(date);
    if(age < 18)
       $('#date_range').val(1).change();
    else if(age >= 18 && age < 25)
       $('#date_range').val(2).change();
    else if(age >= 25 && age < 50)
       $('#date_range').val(3).change();
    else
       $('#date_range').val(4).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="birth-date" >BIRTH DATE</label>
    <input type="date"  class="datepicker" name="birth-date" id="birth-date" >
    <br />
    <label for="date_range" >AGE RANGE</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="date_range" id="date_range">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">- 18</option>
        <option value="2">btw 18 25</option>
        <option value="3">btw 25 50</option>
        <option value="4">50+</option>
    </select>
    
</div>
```

If you want to get better control over date formating and ease the calculations you can use moment.js e.g. the getAge function can be updated as following

```
const getAge = (dob) => {
  const date = moment(dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  return moment().diff(date, 'years');
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Zain Ul Abidin for your support I really appreciate it, one last question if the Birth_date field is empty how to make it display val('5') which means unspecified

Comment: by default you should display val(5) as on page load no date will be selected, once user sets a date there is no way atleast in this date control to clear the selection, however for custom controls when user clears or unset the date simply set the value 5 there

Comment: Thank you very much @Zain Ul Abidin what about Date(dob))/(31556952000)) it's for mm/dd/yyyy what about dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: then you can skip this and use moment library and format in whichever format you prefer

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it,  wish you the best

Comment: What does the ~~ in the return statement mean Mr. Abidin?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin Hi i hope you're doing well thank you for your support, can you check this question please, it's another case "Dropdown menu depends on two date fields using jquery and moment" thank you in advanced.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983962/dropdown-menu-depends-on-two-date-fields-using-jquey